# Postman PUT request: How to see the upload time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, postman

Okay this is a short one: I am uploading files via postman to a AWS S3 bucket via a presigned url.
Is it possible to see the upload progress in percentage? As is possible, for example, in my app with axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is **not possible** with postman. In the browser, however, the time can be calculated.